# How to write a keras lambda layer to turn a 'vector' input layer into a 'image' layer with keras backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have two inputs to the model:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels,))
input_cond = Input(shape=(self.cond_dim,))
```

Their shapes are different, I want to expand each element of `input_cond` into an image that has the same size as `[img_rows,img_cols]`.

I wrote:

```
def conv_cond_concat(tensors):
    x_shapes = tensors[0].get_shape()
    y_shapes = tensors[1].get_shape()
    print (x_shapes,y_shapes)
    return tensors[1]*K.ones([x_shapes[0], x_shapes[1], x_shapes[2], y_shapes[1]])
```

Then:

```
lamb_layer = Lambda(conv_cond_concat)
cond_img = lamb_layer([input_img,input_cond])
```

I got complaints like:

```
  File "/homeXXXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 708, in ones
    return variable(tf.constant_initializer(1., dtype=tf_dtype)(shape),
  File "/home/XXXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 200, in __call__
    self.value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape)
  File "/home/XXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/XXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 380, in make_tensor_proto
    if shape is not None and np.prod(shape, dtype=np.int64) == 0:
  File "/home/XXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2566, in prod
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "/home/XXXanaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 35, in _prod
    return umr_prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: __long__ returned non-long (type NoneType)
```

How should this correctly be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by x_shapes[0]. The first dimension corresponds to batch size and it is None.

I have re-wrote the conv_cond_concat function which will add a dynamic dimension.

```
def conv_cond_concat(tensors):
    x_shapes = tensors[0].get_shape()
    y_shapes = tensors[1].get_shape()
    print (x_shapes,y_shapes)
    tmp = K.placeholder((None, x_shapes[1], x_shapes[2], y_shapes[1]))
    return tensors[1]*K.ones_like(tmp)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to add a dynamic dimension. If so, I would like to know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here's the error msg:  InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lambda_1/Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,128,128,8]. At runtime (?) it needs values for the place holder?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def broadcast(input):
    img = input[0]
    cond = input[1]
    return K.tf.broadcast_to(cond, K.concatenate([K.shape(img), K.shape(cond)[-1:]]))

## Test the implementation
input_img = Input(shape=(4,4,3,))
input_cond = Input(shape=(2,))
output = Lambda(broadcast)([input_img, input_cond])

model = Model([input_img, input_cond], output)
model.predict([np.zeros((1,4,4,3)), np.random.random(2)[None]])
### output shape is (4, 4, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. I need to make sure the broadcast is doing the job correctly.